# compare date entered in textbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

asp.net Code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-5">Received Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div  class="input-group date date-picker" id="recvdate" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRecvdDate" CssClass="form-control tooltips" data-original-title="dd-mm-yyyy" data-placement="top" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn default dtp-btn " id="Button2" type="button" runat="server"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-5">Expiry Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="input-group date date-picker" id="expdate" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiryDate" CssClass="form-control tooltips" onkeyup="validation();" data-original-title="dd-mm-yyyy" data-placement="top" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-btn" id="expiryDatePicker">
                <button class="btn default dtp-btn " id="Button1" type="button" runat="server"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
            <asp:Label ID="lblreasonMessagedvTabNavigationAction" Font-Bold="true" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function validation() {
var startDate = $("[id*=txtRecvdDate]").val();
var endDate = $("[id*=txtExpiryDate]").val();
var newDate = new Date(startDate);
var newToDate = new Date(endDate);
    if (newDate != '' && newToDate !='') {
        if (newDate < newToDate)
        {
            alert("check");
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

I am unable the compare the expiry date with received date textbox. In which expiry date should be greater than received date

Comment: what is happening when you click the button? if there are any error in the console window. please update them here. press F12 and check console

Comment: which the help of debugger i have found that the values newDate and newToDate is 'invalid date', and there is no error in console

Comment: what about startdate and enddate? what are the values in those variables?

Comment: they both have the dates that i have selected

Comment: can you share them here? because the format may cause some issues while converting them.

Comment: var startDate = $("[id*=txtRecvdDate]").val(); //Output is: is 24-09-2020
var newDate = new Date(startDate); // Output is: Invalid Date

And I can't able to compare the dates

Comment: Did you check the below answer? If it helped you to solve the issue. please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have date as dd-mm-yyyy format from textbox(startdate). so when you use it in conversion like new Date(dd-mm-yyyy). It will throw invaliddate. So before converting change its format to yyyy-mm-dd by using below code. because new Date accept datestring in yyyy-mm-dd format.

```js
function validation() {
var startDate = $("[id*=txtRecvdDate]").val();
var newdatestring = startDate.split("-").reverse().join("-");
var newDate= new Date(newdatestring);

var endDate = $("[id*=txtExpiryDate]").val();
var newToDatestring = endDate.split("-").reverse().join("-");
var newToDate= new Date(newToDatestring);

    if (newDate != '' && newToDate !='') {
        if (newDate < newToDate)
        {
            alert("check");
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: If you are using / instead of - then replace - with / in the above code

Comment: Updated answer (changed from newdate to newDate). Check and accept if this solves your problem.